# How to concatenate corresponding columns from multiple files into one single file, using a specified column as ID?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

If I have a number of files, such as

**1.txt**:

```
1;ab, bc
2;cd, de, ef
3;fgh
```

**2.txt**:

```
4;bc
1;cd, ef
5;ab
2;g
```

**3.txt**:

```
5;ef, hl 
7;a, b, c
3;k, jk
1;b
6;x
```

Assuming that `;` is a delimiter and the first column serves as ID, how to concatenate corresponding second columns (using eg. commas), so that the output becomes

**output.txt**:

```
1;ab, bc, cd, ef, b
2;cd, de, ef, g
3;fgh, k, jk
4;bc
5;ab, ef, hl 
7;a, b, c
6;x
```

Comment: Your output example is not sorted on id, but rather based upon the order in which id is first seen in the files read.  Is that correct?  So, what's your preferred output (sorted, ordered, or "just group correctly" [which might be hashkey dependent])?  I think you've got two answers that work, but one of them is piping through sort

Comment: @CraigEstey: yes, I preserved the order (in which ID is first seen in the files read) intentionally because sorting is another part of the problem and will be solved separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F";" '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]","$2:$2} 
          END{for(k in a) print k";"a[k]}' file{1,2,3} | sort 

1;ab, bc,cd, ef,b
2;cd, de, ef,g
3;fgh,k, jk
4;bc
5;ab,ef, hl 
6;x
7;a, b, c
```

Comment: Note that I don't need any sorting at this stage, so you can remove that code. Question: what is `file{1,2,3}`, where are the names of input files and why didn't you include the output file name?

Comment: @lyricallywicked `file{1,2,3}` is [any] shell syntax and expands to `file1 file2 file3`.  Note it is _not_ a wildcard match.  However `file[123]` is wildcard and either produces `file1 file2 file3` or a "No match" error.  It produces `file1 file2` if `file3` doesn't exist. A slightly more expanded version is `file{1,ab,qdl}` which produces `file1 fileab fileqdl`  Here's a larger example: `ab{cd,ef,gh}{ij,kl,mn}` produces `abcdij abcdkl abcdmn abefij abefkl abefmn abghij abghkl abghmn`.  In all cases, the expansion is done by the shell, so the program only sees the result

Comment: @CraigEstey: thanks, and will `[123].txt` produce `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt`?

Comment: @lyricallywicked With the _bracket_ syntax, it follows the rules of wildcard matching, just like *.txt. So, wih `[123].txt` if all of the files exist you get `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt`.  If 2.txt doesn't exist, you'll get `1.txt 3.txt`.  If none exist, bash gives `[123].txt`.  Under csh, wildcard non-matches cause aborts.  You can also use a range like `[1-3].txt`. It's like a regex character class (e.g. [a-z]).

Comment: @lyricallywicked  On the other hand, the _brace_ syntax isn't about filenames at all.  Try `echo {hello,goodbye}_{world,galaxy}`.  For filenames, it's useful if you want to pass a list to a program that will create any missing files.  Hence, `{1,2,3}.txt` will always expand to `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt` and target program will see that 2.txt does not exist [and create it]

Answer (score 0):

cause `join(1)` is designed for join two files, and the input has to be sort, so why bother. the awk source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

BEGIN { FS = ";" }
FNR==NR { a[$1] = $2; next}
{
    if ($1 in a) {
        a[$1] = a[$1] ", " $2
    } else {
        a[$1] = $2;
    }
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        printf("%s%s%s\n", i,FS,a[i]);
    }
}
```